# Checking multiple $_ POST words with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm working with a page that, once a link is called this script checks and if the POST contains the keyword it and then finds that page.  However no matter how I organize this if it doesn't work.

```
<?PHP

if($_POST['page']) {
    $page = (int)$_POST['page']; 
    $exists = file_exists('pages/page_'.$page.'html');
        if($exists) {
            echo file_get_contexnts('pages/page_'.$page.'html');
        } else {
            echo 'There is no such page!';
        }
} else if ($_POST['course']) die("0"); {
    $course = (int)$_POST['course'];
    $exists = file_exists('courses/course_'.$course.'html');
        if($exists) {
            echo file_get_contexnts('courses/course_'.$course.'html'); 
            die("1");
        } else {
            echo 'There is no such page!';
        }               
    } 

?>
```

The error I'm currently receiving with this setup is:

```
Notice: Undefined index: course in C:\wamp\www\Home Page\load_page.php on line 12

Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0003  253944  {main}( )   ..\load_page.php:0
```

Is it because there is no 'course' in the page?  I might be confused of the code I'm modifying a tutorial of a simple ajax website.  It is possible what I am trying to do does not work.

In that case how could I possible go about doing what I want to do.

Right now I have a home page and it loads in another page without switching pages.  I like the floridness of it.  I would like to have a sort of sub call.  So if you are on the home page and you go to courses page then you can click on a specific course and that will load from a different directory within the courses directory.

- Homepage (when you click on courses you go to...)

  - pages/courses_home.html (when you click on a course you go to...)

    - courses/course_1.html (you can view course and then click back to directory above or go to home)

That is the structure I'm looking to try to achieve.

If more information is needed please let me know what and I'll do my best to include it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax should be:

```
if(isset($_POST["page"])) {

} elseif(isset($_POST["course"])) {

}
```

I am not sure why you have a die statement there, but I don't think it belongs. Also, keep in mind the logic for what happens if neither of these conditions is met.

Edit: also keep in mind that isset doesn't prevent empty strings, so you may want to check for that as well. A function you could use is

```
function checkPost($value) {
    return isset($_POST[$value]) && $_POST[$value] !== "";
}
```

To use:

```
if(checkPost('page')) {
    //some logic
}
```

Comment: I believe this is probably the most logical answer.  I appreciate your help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong syntax.

```
elseif ($_POST['course']) {
```

without die statement.If 'course' undefined else statement works and does not get error. Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if isset(($_POST['page'])) {

...

} else if isset(($_POST['course'])) die("0"); {
```

instead of this:

```
if($_POST['page']) {

...

} else if ($_POST['course']) die("0"); {
```

Comment: I get: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'isset' (T_ISSET), expecting '(' in C:\wamp\www\Home Page\load_page.php on line 3

Comment: Try 

if isset(($_POST['page'])) {

//...

} else if isset(($_POST['course']))  {


   die("0");

}